# Health-Themed Food Tasting with Noom in NYC!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

On Wednesday January 18th, from 7-9pm EST, Stack Exchange will be co-hosting a health and nutrition-themed food tasting with [Noom Weight Loss](http://www.noom.com/).

The event will take place at the Noom Headquarters in NYC. There will be a bunch of tasty dishes to sample, and some will be healthier than others. For example, we might have one traditionally prepared pie, and another that has no added sugar. The challenge to our guests will be to guess which is which!

Whether you're a chef, foodie, or just someone trying to keep a New  Year's Resolution to eat healthy, come join us for some free food, wine, and great ideas for healthy recipes.

Check out the [Eventbrite page](http://deliciousandnutritious.eventbrite.com/) to RSVP and get directions.

Comment: How did the event go?

Comment: It was really fun! We didn't have as great of a turn out as we'd hoped (did all our advertising through Eventbrite), but it was still a great event.